# TCL braces and variable scope

Tags: tcl

I have some strange TCL behavior that I don't understand relative to the use of braces and variable scope. In the two line snippet below I create a variable quickMode and set it to 0.  I then try to use the variable within a ternary and apply braces to stop double conversion.  I get an error that says quickMode can't be read and isn't a variable.  If I remove the curly braces, I clear the error.  Can anyone explain this behavior?

```
set quickMode 0
set frameSizeIncrement      [ mpexpr {$quickMode == 1 ? 600 : 3}]

can't read "quickMode": no such variable
    while executing
"expr {$quickMode == 1 ? 600 : 3}"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval expr $args"
    (procedure "mpexpr" line 1)
    invoked from within
"mpexpr {$quickMode == 1 ? 600 : 3}"
    invoked from within
"set frameSizeIncrement      [ mpexpr {$quickMode == 1 ? 600 : 3}]"
    (file "tests/basics/ingress_egress.tcl" line 101)
```

Comment: Looks like `mpexpr` is poorly coded, and does not evaluate the expression in the same stack frame as the caller (looks like it should `uplevel 1 [list expr $args]` instead of `eval expr $args`). You could work around this by explicitly putting the variable in the global scope: `set ::quickMode 0; ... mpexpr {$::quickMode ...`

Comment: That's curious; the [`mpexpr` package](http://mpexpr.sourceforge.net/) that I can find is written in C and wouldn't produce that error message…

Comment: I am using TCL 8.4, so it's a bit older. It turns out this problem only seems to show up if I am using a ternary statement.  I tried other usages and the results are as expected.  Thanks for the feedback.  I'll probably just look at updating the TCL installation.